# CSS style syntax meanings

Tags: html, css

What the meaning of the above syntax and how it affects the Webpage?

```
 body,
html {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It says that the whole web page describe by your CSS.

In your code:

`height:100` - the page will cover the whole screen size 
`margin: 0;` - there will be no margin on body and html tags 
`font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` - These will be the font-styles of the text